# custom monolog logging channel in symfony2 command

Tags: php, symfony

In this [cookbook article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/dic_tags.html#dic-tags-monolog), we can see how to use a custom channel in a service. But how can I use a custom login channel in a command ?

I created a symfony2 command to perform something. I would like to use monolog to log things done by my command.

Actually, I want to write log for my command in another file than the logs of the application.

Comment: I want to know how to do this too

Comment: Answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169114/how-to-write-logs-from-one-service-into-separate-file/8210892#8210892

Comment: thanks, I answered my question with this link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A similar question were asked and answered here:

[How to write logs from one service into separate file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169114/how-to-write-logs-from-one-service-into-separate-file/8210892#8210892)

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Any custom command that extends `ContainerAwareCommand`, has access to Symfony's service container. You can define a service that logs in a custom channel in your config.

```
<services>
    <service id="console.logger" parent="monolog.logger_prototype">
        <argument index="0">mychannel</argument>
    </service>
</services>
```

You can access your service from the command the following way

```
$logger = $this->getContainer()->get('console.logger');
```

This logger will log with channel as "mychannel".

FYI The default logger service logs to channel "app". This can be seen in the file
`Symfony/Bundle/MonologBundle/Resources/config/monolog.xml`. This is also the place where the default `logger` service is defined.

```
<services>
    <service id="monolog.logger" parent="monolog.logger_prototype" public="false">
        <argument index="0">app</argument>
    </service>

    <service id="logger" alias="monolog.logger" />

    <service id="monolog.logger_prototype" class="%monolog.logger.class%" abstract="true">
        <argument /><!-- Channel -->
    </service>
</services>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this, use the library directly

```php
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;

// ...

// create a log channel
$log = new Logger('name');
$log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('path of log file', Logger::WARNING));

//add the erros to log file

try {
    //do something
} catch(Exception $e) {
    $log->addError($e->getMessage());
}
```

Maybe this can resolve your problem, add this into your command file.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, your command extends ContainerAwareCommand (as seen here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console.html#creating-a-basic-command).

This means that your command has access to Symfony's service container - which is a big bag of all of the services inside Symfony (i.e. the useful objects). In your case, you need the `logger` service, which you can get by grabbing it out of the container:

```
$logger = $this->getContainer()->get('logger');
```

(reference: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console.html#getting-services-from-the-service-container)

Now you can use the logger as normal. If you ever need any other services, just check out the `php app/console container:debug` command, which lists every single service on the container.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know how to use the logger. I would like to know how I can use a custom channel for this logger. I would like to log the results of my command in another file.

Answer (score 0):

For Symfony 3.3 because of autowire services when you want to log on seperate files follow this approach:

For example let us suppose we need to log on 2 rotating files:

- `exception.log`: For exceptions caused in the application.
- `dataFetch.log`: For calls to an api tha retrieves the applications data.

The on `services.yml` put:

```
monolog:
  channels: ['dataFetch', 'exception']

  handlers:

    dataFetch:
     type: 'rotating_file'
     level: info
     type: stream
     path: 'dataFetch.log'
     max_files: 7
     channels: dataFetch

    exception:
         type: 'rotating_file'
         level: error
         type: stream
         path: 'exception.log'
         max_files: 7
         channels: exception
```

Now for the exception loger you can inject ad dependency the `monolog.logger.exception` while for the dataFetch you can dependency inject the `monolog.logger.dataFetch`.