# Symfony 2.1 - Switch Monolog channel in controller

Tags: php, logging, symfony-2.1, monolog

I want to log into a different file than the usual dev.log or prod.log

I know that this can be done with different channels and I used it in several services, but I'm not very clear about switching the Monolog channel in a controller.

In a service you just define the channel via the `tags` attribute in the service definition, but how can I do this in a controller or even better in a specific action?

I know that a possible solution would be this: [Symfony 2 : Log into a specific file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241528/symfony-2-log-into-a-specific-file)

But it seems overkill to define two new services just for logging to a custom file.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The only way to do this is to define your [controller as a service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html) and inject a custom logger with a custom channel.

Since the channels are created automatically there is currently no other way, but it's an interesting request and you're not the first, so I created an [issue on MonologBundle](https://github.com/symfony/MonologBundle/issues/39) to allow the definition of channels at the bundle configuration level. That way you could just fetch the proper logger from the controller using `$this->get('monolog.logger.mychannel')` (which you can already do if the channel exists, but not if you want a custom channel for the controller that nothing else uses).

**Update:**

As of symfony/monolog-bundle 2.4.0 you can define additional channels as:

```
monolog:
    channels: ["foo", "bar"]
```

Then you can retrieve it as `$this->get('monolog.logger.mychannel')`

Comment: @JohannesKlauß the upcoming release of the bundle I'll make tomorrow includes a proper fix for this btw.

Answer (score 6):

I know that this is an older post, but I ran into a similar need using symfony/monolog-bundle 2.1.x. I couldn't seem to find exactly what I needed in other threads, so I'm documenting my solution here, which was to create a logger container that used a custom channel.

In config.yml

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        user_actions:
            type: stream 
            path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%-user-actions.log"
            level: info 
            channels: [user_actions]
```

In my bundle's services.yml

```
acme.logger.user_actions:
    class: Acme\MyBundle\Monolog\UserActionsLogger
    arguments: ['@logger']
    tags:
        - { name: monolog.logger, channel: user_actions }
```

In src/Acme/MyBundle/Monolog/UserActionsLogger.php

```
<?php

namespace Acme\MyBundle\Monolog;

class UserActionsLogger
{
    public $logger;

    public function __construct($logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
}
```

Then you can either inject the logger container into another service with:

```
acme.user.authenticationhandler:
    class: %acme.user.authenticationhandler.class%
    public: false
    arguments:  ['@router', '@security.context', '@acme.logger.user_actions']
```

Or, you could selectively use the logger container as a service in any controller:

```
$userActionsLogger = $this->get('acme.logger.user_actions');
```

Then you can access the actual logger by:

```
$userActionsLogger->logger->info('A thing happened!')
```

Answer (score 3):

I am currently using symfony/monolog-bundle 2.3.0 and the following code works.

Configuration in `config.yml`

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:  stream
            path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
            level: info
        doctrine:
            type:  stream
            path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/doctrine_%kernel.environment%.log
            level: debug
            channels: doctrine
```

On Controllers

```
$doctrineLogger = $this->get('monolog.logger.doctrine');
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is working, it is only missing `channels: ['doctrine']` before handlers