# How to create one log file per session?

Tags: symfony, logging, monolog, symfony-2.6

I want to create for each session an own logfile.
I have seen that it is possible to create an own logger ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8170048/390177)):

```
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;

// create a log channel
$log = new Logger('name');
$log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('path/to/your.log', Logger::WARNING));

// add records to the log
$log->addWarning('Foo');
$log->addError('Bar');
```

Is it possible to connect it to a session directly using a service or implemented monolog handler?
Overwriting the path is clear for me.

Comment: What you can do is name the log file with the session value

Comment: remember to manage destroyed session (impl custom handler)

Comment: @AhmedDaou Which handler does support that?

Comment: @CSchulz  something like this `'path/to/your_'.$_SESSION['session'].'log'`

Comment: Hum ... so it is finally no registered service or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own handler :

```
class LogSessionHandler extends AbstractProcessingHandler
{
  protected $session;

  public function setSession(\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session $session)
  {
    $this->session = $session;
  }

  protected function write(array $record)
  {
    $fp = fopen('/path/to/log/'.$this->session->getId().'.log','a');
    if ($fp) fwrite($fp, (string) $record['formatted']);
    fclose($fp);
  }
}
```

In services.yml:

```
logger_session:
    class: ..\..\SessionDatabaseHandler
    calls:
        - [ setSession, [ @session ] ]
```

In config_prod.yml:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        ...
        session:
            type: service
            level: error
            id: logger_session
```